# How do I validate the date format in a TextBox, and when editing display in that format

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I have a UserForm that requires dates.

How do I validate that they are dates?

I noticed that my edit function that calls back the values, the dates I entered that look like dates in the Excel sheet look like this in the TextBox.
[image: the date saved is 07/01/2023]

I want to:

1. display the date properly when editing
2. add a validation to be sure that these TextBoxes only allow dates (MM/DD/YYYY)

Answer (score 0):

There are not only one interpretation of this task (if i fully understand). This is one of that. (This not require VBA coding)

- Bind the TextBox to a cell of a sheet.
  In the Properties window of the TextBox set the ControlSource property to a cell.
  e.g. Sheets1!A5
- Set the cell (on Sheets1) NumberFormat property (Right click->Format Cell->Number->Date (in
  category)). Select the appropriate format
- Set the cell validation parameters on the toolbar as required.

After this, when you change one of them the other also changes.

The TextBox accept "anything" and return as text. To validate it a code can be added to the Change or Exit event.

Later in coding both properties can be accessed for the actual value.

Comment: is there a way to change the text that pops up when editing an existing date that in my userform ? the date doesnt appear justr the numbers in the screenshot

Comment: Format the cell's displaying format as the 2nd step in the answer. Then if you type a text in the textbox which can be identified as a date (e.g. 21/5/23), or simply an integer value, after Enter pressed a date will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

i Fixed by adding a "'" before the number when submited to make excel not auto format it to a date so the edit works properly

```
 frmForm.TxtFecha.Value = "'" & frmForm.TxtFecha.Value
```